# Jumping to a specific line in code using C

Tags: c++, c

Sorry if this question is silly, but I can't seem to find the answer on Google. I haven't done C programing in a while and for the life of me remember how, in C or C++, to jump back (or forward) to a specific line in code. If I remember right, there was a way to do this.

Thanks for the help!

Cheers!

Comment: [Beware](http://xkcd.com/292/).

Comment: Just take a special note that just about every person here that's offering a solution is advising against it. `goto` will work in your instance, but it would probably be better to restructure your program's code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The infamous goto, in conjuntion with labels.

```
label_name:
goto label_name;
```

Before using it, search for 'goto considered harmful'.

Comment: The style of programming railed against in "Go To Statement Considered Harmful" has been dead for decades.

Comment: @Chris Lutz You mean jumping to some arbitrary line resulting in spaghetti code? Well the question seems to imply at least the possibility of that ;) Gotos are useful in c++ for stuff like local error handling and similar things sure, but you can easily abuse them.

Comment: @Voo That sounds like using gotos to implement the more idiomatic do { } while( error );

Comment: @Voo - Perhaps. Checking the OP's profile, he's had a lot of activity in the Java tag, which means he probably knows the regular flow control statements but has forgotten about `goto`, which isn't present in Java, and has a need for it now. I doubt he's trying to emulate `while` loops with `goto`.

Comment: @K-ballo - I think he's referring to `type *x = malloc(sizeof *x); if(!x) goto ERR1; x->member = malloc(sizeof *x->member); if(!x->member) goto ERR2; /* initialize x and x->member */; return x; ERR2: free(x); ERR1: return NULL;` which conveniently handles freeing one or more nested members in the event that one of the allocations fails without ending up with a million levels of indentation.

Comment: @K-ballo Chris nailed it. There are situations where using local gotos can simplify the code (major example: linux kernel, they use that quite a lot), though it's more something you use in C or if you can't use RAII for whatever reasons.

Comment: @Chris Lutz Sure it's a possibility. But mentioning the paper and why it can be problematic seemed appropriate imho. If he's using it in a reasonable way, he'll notice that there's no problem and otherwise he may think about it again. Also if you're writing new code in C++ using RAII basically eliminates the only reason why I personally use gotos; there may be some other cases, but I'd think those are extremely rare.

Comment: @Voo - In C++ you never need `goto`, I agree. The question is a bit unclear as to which one the OP is actually using.

Answer (score 5):

C and C++ do not have a concept of 'lines' after the preprocessing stage. As such, you cannot 'jump' to a line of code.

If you want to jump to a line of code in your editor, this depends on what editor you are using. If you want to jump to a specific *statement* (not *line*) at *runtime*, you could use `goto`, but this should be avoided for most circumstances, as it leads to difficult to understand code, and other control-flow structures are more appropriate in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the nasty and easy solution: `goto` and then a label which indicates the line of code you want to go to.

Normally though, you'd have a function with the specific functionality you want to invoke, and call that function.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `goto` statement, like this:

```
goto SomeLine;

// Code code code...

SomeLine:
```

Note that this is considered extremely bad practice.  Chances are, there's a better way to organize your code that avoids the need altogether.

Answer (score 3):

I do also think that the goto instruction should not be used when you can help it.

However, contrary to many other languages, there isn't a neat way to exit from multi-layered if() blocks and the easiest is to the goto in this case.

What I suggest is that you add comments and use wisely named labels (l1: ... goto l1; sucks.)

Note that people will tell you that the goto is bad, and use the break and continue statements in loops like crazy. They have the exact same *side* effect as the goto instruction and could be considered as bad (but aren't).

Comment: Goto instruction may break order of creating and deleting objects in c++. So it is dangerous feature of language. But I agree with you that sometimes it makes code clearer and smaller than code with continue or break statements but without goto.

Comment: @George: What do you mean by "Goto instruction may break order of creating and deleting objects"?

Comment: Something like this: http://www.chris-lott.org/resources/cstyle/Wildfire-C++Style.html#HDR38

Comment: @George: Unless Object has a trivial default constructor and destructor, that code is illegal and will not compile.  And if it is trivial, there's no harm done.

Comment: I've checked and I now agree with you. It is common misconception. In normal compilers goto instruction doesn't break order of creating and deleting of objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options to do it: 'goto' instruction, setjmp/longjmp functions. Also you can use in c++ SEH (exception propagation and handling), but it isn't simple. And if you really nead such thing as jumping to particular line of code, I will recommend you to rewrite your code using loops and conditionals with additional state variables.  Because you have serious problem with structure or design of  your code. It may look ugly but it is more safer than using goto and other "black magic"

Comment: "SEH"? `throw` and `catch` are less simple than `setjmp`/`longjmp`? These are new to me, but I suspect they are instead old. Also, condition variables are more complicated than `goto` when they only increase the number of states the program may be in at any line of code. If the state in an `if` block exactly corresponds to that required by a certain point in the `else` block, it may be better to `goto` where you need to be, than to introduce a loop which is supposed to execute at most once.